# Dart Pirate Tutorial Doesn't Download JSON after build (step 7)

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I did the Google Dart tutorial (pirate name badge: https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/) all the way through and it ran exactly as expected until I hit step 7 where I run the build on my normal browser.

What happens is the page loads, but it never seems to complete the async download of the JSON file, so the input and button never become enabled and Chrome keeps spinning because it's waiting on localhost (127.0.0.1).

I imagine this is because I'm not running a web server?

What would I have to do to get this sample app to run on my local machine?

Thanks!

Browser: Chrome 42.0.2311.90

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not running a web server? You could just run `pub serve web` from the package folder (where the `pubspec.yaml` file is) and load the page from `http://localhost:8080/piratebadge.html`.

Your `<Dart-SDK>/bin` directory needs to be added to your systems `PATH` in order to make `pub serve web` work.

If you use DartEditor just use the `run` context menu on the `piratebadge.html` file and it launches `pub serve` automatically.

Comment: I did launch the final step from the context menu. And when I launched the development project for all the steps it worked fine. The final step has me click the built HTML file and select "Run in Browser", which is the point at which I encountered this.

Comment: Do you get any error message? In DartEditor or in Chrome dev-tools (press F12 in the browser)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

With a reference to: http://127.0.0.1:3030/darrrt/1-blankbadge/build/web/piratebadge.dart

Comment: Doesn't look like you are loading it using `pub serve`. If you open it from DartEditor (`6-piratebadge/web/piratebadge.html`) this should work or at least show a different error message.

Comment: Yep, that stage works perfectly well. I'm trying to run the built web app to double-check that it works (since I don't currently have a web server to upload it to) in deployment. But that probably means I should be running at least a simple web server on the build directory.

Comment: Yup, otherwise you need to add command line options like `--allow-file-access-from-files` when you start chrome. If you start the built output you will always get the mentioned error because there is still an obsolete dart script tag in the `piratebadge.html` file. I assume this will be changed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a new bug in the DartEditor on Mac (and Linux), see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23431&thanks=23431&ts=1431391466

One way to work around this is to start your own http server, e.g. 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer' in the build/web directory and then goto http://localhost:8000/piratebadge.html.